# Scanning unique file extensions into a variable

Tags: java, regex, windows, cmd, file-extension

I have a windows directory containing tens of thousands of files. I need a list of all the unique file extensions to be put in a variable.

In a java program, I would like to scan through that directory (recursively, including all sub-directories) and retrieve a list of unique file extensions that can be put into a variable.

Ex: Dir contains: File1.txt File2.doc File3.doc File4.doc File5.ppt
I would like to retrieve "txt,doc,ppt" and put that into a string variable (They do not have to be separated in an array of any type - although that would work. I only need to end up with a string of them, like the one above).

Is there anyway I can do this? Possibly by accessing the command line or using regex?

Comment: Please share your code and let us know where you stuck. There are 2 things involved 1) look for all directories and folder 2) regex to match file names.

Comment: Have you tried `String.endsWith()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Java 8 example as String:

```java
        final String extensions = Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
                .map(Path::toString)
                .filter(pathString -> pathString.contains("."))
                .map(pathString -> pathString.substring(pathString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, pathString.length()))
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        System.out.println(extensions);
```

As an array:

```java
     final String[] extensions = Files.walk(Paths.get(""))
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .map(Path::toString)
                .filter(pathString -> pathString.contains("."))
                .map(pathString -> pathString.substring(pathString.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, pathString.length()))
                .distinct()
                .toArray(String[]::new);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(extensions));
```

Comment: How can I do this but return a String array of extensions rather than concatenating them into a single string?

Comment: @SteveW I have added the array example.

Answer (score 0):

here is a batch-solution:

```
del %temp%\x.x 2>nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a-d *') do (find "%%~xi" %temp%\x.x ||<nul set/p .= %~xi>>x.x)
set /p ext=<%temp%\x.x
set ext=%ext:.=,%
set ext=%ext:~1%
echo %ext%
```

Comment: @EJP: Question clearly states "Possibly by accessing the command line " Also the Tag "cmd" is given.

Answer (score 0):

For a `cmd` (batch file) solution

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions
    for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*) do if not defined "\%%~xa\" (echo(%%~xa&set ""\%%~xa\"=1")
    endlocal
```

This uses the environment to store the information of seen extensions by setting a variable for each one. If the variable is not set, this is the first time the extension is found and is echoed to console.

**edited** to adapt to comments and to OP that i have misread. The output needs to be in only one line

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions
    for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.*) do if not defined "\%%~xa\" (
        set ""\%%~xa\"=1" 
        if not defined "\" (set ""\"=1" ) else (<nul set /p ".=,")
        <nul set /p ".=%%~xa"
    )
    endlocal
```

Same working that the previous code, but in this case the output is keept in one line with commas added when needed to separate the elements in the extensions list

**edited** to properly format the output: remove the dots from extension and store the data in a variable

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    for /f "delims=" %%z in ('cmd /e:on /v:off /q /c "for /r "%cd%" %%a in (*.*) do if not defined "\%%~xa\" (set ""\%%~xa\"^=1" & if not defined "\" (set ""\"^=1" ) else (<nul set /p ".^=^,") & <nul set /p ".^=%%~xa" )"') do set "extensionList=%%z"
    set "extensionList=%extensionList:.=%"
    echo(%extensionList%

    endlocal
```

Still the same code, but to get the data inside a variable, all the previous logic has been moved inside a `for` command, so the list from previous version can be assigned to a variable. Then the dots are removed from that variable to get the required output.

Comment: OP wants them in a string: "txt,doc,ppt", not on single lines. Besides that, nice solution (no temp-file).

Comment: @Stephan, thank you, i missed that part of the question.

Comment: Hm. How about removing the dots? And where is the variable for later use?

Comment: @Stephan, maybe i'm wrong, this is what i understand: the OP will make use of it from a java program, accessing the underlying OS (windows in this case) to retrieve the information. Once the OS has done its work giving the string to the calling program, removing the dots is trivial. Anyway, to fulfill with the indicated sample, code has been updated.